# In Scala, how can I merge maps as below?

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

I would like to know how I can merge maps in Scala.

```
val prevMap = Map(1-> Set("a"), 2-> Set("b"))
val newMap = Map(2-> Set("a","b"),1-> Set("c"))
val expected = Map(1->Set("a","c"), 2-> Set("a","b"))
```

Basically, expected map is newMap + add all values that had a different key between prev and new

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using the standard library, like this,

```
m1 ++ m2.map { case (k,v) => k -> (v ++ m1.getOrElse(k,Set())) }
```

Consider the first occurrence of `++`, for appending maps. The key value pairs of the right operand of `++` are enhanced by merging sets from `m1` with a common key, then for any key occurring in `m1` and `m2`, the operator `++` replaces the key value pair in `m1` with the key value pair in `m2`; key value pairs in `m1` where the key does not occur in `m2` are preserved.

The second occurrence of `++` denotes the set union method. Thus, sets of those keys that occur only in `m2` remain intact (set union with empty set).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't know that there is a built-in function for that (after all, it depends on the specific `Set` value type). Here is the most compact I was able to come up with (assume maps are called `a` and `b`)

```
(a.keySet | b.keySet) map { k => k -> (a.getOrElse(k, Set.empty) | b.getOrElse(k, Set.empty)) } toMap
```